# Can I fix my metabo hedge trimmer myself?

Tags: tools, tool-maintenance

I use an electric metabo hedge trimmer. Both hands need to be on separate switches for it to run. When I let go of both switches simultaneously, the blades stop immediately. However, when I only let go of one of the switches, the blades stop gradually. My father has the same model and his does not have the same behaviour.

Can I easily fix this myself or should I let someone service it?

Comment: You should read the instructions, to see if this is the expected behaviour (newer model have new safety rules/implementation). If it is not the expected behaviour (and we are talking about safety feature), you should ask your seller to repair it. It is expected that any stuffs that it is sold it follows the minimum safety rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Simply don't**. Trimmer are kind of tricky tools. Moreover if it is an electric model.

If you have no idea on what to do or where to start to find the issue, you should go ask for specialized advice.

you indeed easily can leave a finger in those. Don't test your luck with that.

Comment: I just had two fingers caught in there, that's why I'm asking... In the manual of a gas powered one I read that the safety feature could be fine tuned manually, so I wondered whether the electric one had such a feature. I'll go with your advice now.

Comment: And Seul, you always wear safety glasses and hearing protection!  I'll have to tell you about two of my guys who naughtily went around  the corner to take off said safety glasses.  2 lost eyes...

Comment: Sorry to hear that! Yes, I learned my lesson. Got proper gloves, glasses, helmet and all now. A friend, who is a tree surgeon, told me about a nose lost to a hedge trimmer...

Answer (score 4):

Sounds as if a sensor is gooed up.  If you are able to keep the dirt out of engines those engines will last forever!  You need an introduction to your repair crew who if you butter them up will teach you all you need to know I kid you not!  In one inexpensive visit you will get valuable know how so that you will be able to fix most 2 stroke/cycle engines!  You will take that time of that visit to get a few back up filters, spark plugs.  Air filter and gas filter. Have them just do a cleaning!  Hang out with them if you can!  Find a well to do small engine repair place, mom and dad? Never use any gas with ethanol.  Use perfectly measured oil in the gas. I ran a business and doing this brown nosing with my chosen repair company saved huge bucks! Sweet hearts!  Let's see, I am talking about 3 different repair companies.  Paid off!!

Even though your trimmer is electric the same principles apply.  That grease needs to be added and cleaned away.  Are you hedging?  (keep the bottom of the hedge WIDER than the top).  Sharpen blades every single time you use it.  That might just be the problem, gooed up reciprocating blades?!!! Don't use WD40.  Use a silicone spray. Learn how to sharpen your blades with a file.  Clean residue of plants and oil off the blades as you sharpen.  Each time you finish hedging.

Comment: I have to add, gas powered tools are far better than electric.  My opinion but using these things for a living day in and day out and day in and...make for a certifiable opinion.  ha ha.  Stihl is still my favorite for new stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your advice mate. In the manual of a gas powered one I read that the safety feature could be fine tuned manually, so I wondered whether the electric one had such a feature. Now I think I'll just take it to a repair shop and while I still have the cast I got thanks to the glitch I can just as well use it as a starting point for a chat, I only use the trimmer once or twice a year, but I'll start cleaning it more and, indeed, learn how to sharpen it. Any tip for a video to start with?

Comment: Start with your repair guys even if it is only electric.  I am sure they will love to share with you the wonders of gas powered trimmers/equipment!  I just had to go USE my gas powered hedgers, line trimmers and blowers to feel rejuvenated.  OH MY!  I got the lawn edged, weeds wacked, debris blown in place and now I really feel good!  Great tools will encourage or rather entice you to use them!  No longer work but a drug fix of superiority!!  Okay, I do take it too far...grins!  I'll look for a decent video to send, Seul!